# Assets from one Rails app are being temporarily applied after navigating to another Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am just starting to work with Ruby (2.3), Rails (5), Apache (v2.2), and Passenger.
I'm seeing a glitch in the which CSS files are getting loaded:  the CSS and JavaScript from one Rails app are being temporarily retained when I navigate to another Rails app.
I haven't found the magic combination of search terms for such an odd problem.

Here are the details:
I have a Rails app, called "Index", that displays a list of links to other Rails apps.
I have modified the Index's CSS (using SCSS) to make the UI prettier.

When I click on an Index link, the expected Rails app displays, but somehow retains the CSS from the Index page.
If I press F5, the page refreshes and stops using the CSS from the Index page.

The problem happens every time I follow a link from the Index to any of the Rails apps.
If I go back and forth between the Index page and any of the Rails apps, the problem will occur every time.

It happens in both Chrome and Firefox.
I have added the following lines to the end of my passenger.conf.  (I am currently accessing my new Index page via https://.../xyz.)

```
    Alias /xyz /var/www/html/index/public
    <Location /xyz>
      PassengerBaseURI /xyz
      PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/index
    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/html/index>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

If I click on an Index link and inspect the sources for the newly loaded page, I can see assets (.css and .js) from \xyz (my Index page).
The newly loaded pages have no knowledge of the Index page, so I can't figure out how it's possible for them to be pulling those assets.
If I press F5 (to reload the page) the \xyz assets disappear.
I don't know if this is a Passenger thing, a Rails thing, or a CSS thing.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The revelation came when someone noticed that JavaScript was unexpectedly involved in following my links.
My Index page was using Turbolinks, which was using AJAX to load the Rails app that I was navigating to.
The AJAX call left the existing .css and .js assets in place.
Pressing F5 caused the page to fully reload, which eliminated the unwanted assets.

The solution, in my case, is to not use Turbolinks on my Index page.